# Infinite scroll using redux and react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, redux, single-page-application

I am trying to implemet infinite scroll in a react based application that uses Redux for state management I am trying to dispatch an action on page scroll. But not able to achieve the same. My code is here

```
// The Reducer Function
const pinterestReducer = function (state=[], action) {
    if (action.type === 'SET_CONTENT') {
        state = action.payload;
    }
    return state;
}

const appReducer = combineReducers({
  pinterest: pinterestReducer
})

// Create a store by passing in the pinterestReducer
var store = createStore(appReducer);
window.onscroll = function(ev) {
    if ((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= document.body.offsetHeight) {
        // you're at the bottom of the page, show all data
store.dispatch({
    type: 'SET_CONTENT',
    payload: travelJSON 
});
    }
};
```

travelJSON is an array of objects. Initialy I dispatch an action that assigns the first 12 objects of travelJSON to state. When user scrolls to bottom of page I have to assign full JSON Below is my component making use of this state:

```
// Dispatch our first action to change the state
store.dispatch({
    type: 'SET_CONTENT',
    payload: travelJSON.slice(0,12)
});
    render(
        <Provider store={store}><Pinterest /></Provider>,
        document.getElementById('page-container'));
```

Comment: You haven't shown any code that would load more data. What is `travelJSON`?

Comment: updated the question. Please have a look.

Answer (score 1):

I would question why you are trying to do this in the model/business logic layer.  Typically virtualizing a scroll is a view state concern.  You give the view component the entire list of model objects, but it only renders the DOM elements for the objects that would be shown in the viewport of the view component.

One way to do this is to create a component that allocates a div which is tall enough to display every single one of your model objects.  The render method renders only those items that would be displayed in the viewport.

There are a number of components that do this for you already.  See for example: https://github.com/developerdizzle/react-virtual-list.  This is implemented as an HOC, so you could implement it with your current view logic with minimal changes.

It wraps your component. You send your entire data array into the wrapper, and it figures out which elements will be displayed in the viewport and passes those to the wrapped component, it also passes in the 'paddingTop' style required to shift those elements into the viewport considering the current scroll position.

Answer (score 0):

The following code removes the first 12 items from travelJSON

```
travelJSON.splice(0,12)
```

on scroll you replace the first 12 items with the remaining items, while you should really add them instead of replace them.

```
state = action.payload
```

To add items to your state use something like this:

```
return [...state, ...action.payload];
```

(This uses the new spread operator: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator )

Comment: @angular2 just edited his code - my solution was assuming he uses splice not slice

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [react waypoint](http://brigade.github.io/react-waypoint/)? It seems like a nice component to accomplish exactly what you are trying to do?